# Configurable Product Show Out of Stock Simple Product in Dropdown

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product, simple-product, inventory, backorder

I am currently using Magento 1.8.1.0 and I am having some inventory issues with Configurable Products. I am trying to show Out of Stock Simple Products in the Dropdown but let the Customer know it is out of stock when selected. As far as I can tell, the only time a customer is notified it's backordered is after they place the order, which they are then notified in the confirmation email.

I have attached a screenshot of the Configurable Product in question.

There is another Simple Product associated with this Configurable Product but it's currently set to Out of Stock in Inventory, so it is not displayed.

[image: Configurable Product]

What I am trying accomplish is when the highlighted product (it has a negative inventory already) is selected, I want it to show the "Out of Stock" text by the price like it does for Simple Products that are Out of Stock. (2nd Screenshot in green box)

[image: Simple Product Out of Stock]

I have the inventory settings set for the Simple Products within the Configurable Product:

[image: Inventory Settings for Simple Product]

If this product is set to Out of Stock, it is not displayed as an option. I want our customers to know we manufacture this product but we do not have any in stock at the moment.

If I was able to add (Out of Stock) after the Product Name in the Dropdown, that would be sufficient as well.

A Simple Product acts in a very similar way to the Configurable Product, when the inventory is set the same as the Simple Products within a Configurable Product (3rd screenshot). Meaning no Out of Stock text is displayed:

[image: Simple Product with Inventory set]

Once I headed to the checkout after adding a Configurable Product and Simple Product to the cart (both with negative inventories and backorders available below 0), I noticed a red asterisk below the Product Name? Is this supposed to have some text stating the product is going to be backordered? If that's the case, I would not need any other changes. I will investigate and see what is supposed to be there in the mean time.

[image: Cart Image]

Any of the 3 possible solutions will be more than adequate. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a slightly different issue but I have notice you have a negative value on the product quantity.My settings are no backorders are allowed ,the product value will be  0 before reindex and after reindex the product quantity jumps to -1. What could cause such a change . Please help if you managed to resolve your issue